# ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpressionが親のメタデータを参照する

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

ASP.NET MVC2でCustomHelperを作っています。

必要な情報が取得できない問題があったので、
解決方法があればご教示ください。

ViewModelにDisplayName属性やValidationAttributeをつけています。

属性を取得する際はModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression()で取得できますが、
対象のViewModelがBaseViewModelをoverrideしている場合、
BaseViewModelの属性（たとえばDisplayName）を取得するようです。
※今回の場合、BaseViewModelにはDisplayName属性をつけていないので
　取得できない

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelExFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

        return LabelExFor(html, expression, metadata.IsRequired);
    }
```

ViewではBaseViewModelをoverrideしたViewModelを用いているので
ViewModelの属性を取得したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

尚、ViewModelのプロパティをoverrideではなくnewで定義した場合は
ViewModelの属性を取ってくるようです。

## 最終的な回避方法

標準の`LabelFor`は用いず、自作の`LabelExFor`で置き換える。`LabelExFor`では`FromLambdaExpression()`ではなく、`FromStringExpression()`を用いてmetadataの取得を行う。

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelExFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), html.ViewData);

    string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? 
                        metadata.PropertyName ?? 
                        htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
    （以下略）
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

現行の`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression`の[ソース](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/ModelBinding/ModelMetadata.cs)の290行目で、

```
containerType = memberExpression.Expression.Type;
```

とコンテナ型を求めている箇所が`System.Web.Mvc.dll`のバージョン2.0.0.0では

```
containerType = body.Member.DeclaringType;
```

となっているため、過去に不具合修正が入っているのだと思われます。

### 拡張メソッドでの回避方法

例えば`LabelFor`の場合、以下のように拡張メソッドを実装すれば`ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression`を利用します。なお拡張メソッドの利用には`web.config`の編集が必要です。

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public MvcHtmlString LabelFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return html.Label(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    }
}
```

これでもダメであれば自分で`ModelMetadata`と`HtmlHelper`を作って`LabelForModel`に渡すか、自分でHTMLを作るしかないように思われます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
まだテストできていない状況ですがアドバイスを元にチェックします。

Comment: MVC2標準のLabelForでも同様の問題はあるようでした。
（ValidationAttributeは正しく想定どおりのものをとってくるのですが…）

アドバイスを元に調べてCustom ModelMetadataProviderを作ることはできたのですが、modelAccessorよりMetadataを取得（作成）する方法がわかりませんでした。もし、参考になるページなどがあれば教えていただければと思います。

Comment: @HidetoshiKamata 実装例を追記しました。Global.asaxで`ModelMetadataProvider.Current`を指定しておけば`LabelFor`内の`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression`にも影響するはずですが、モデルの設計によってはパフォーマンスが悪化する可能性もあります。

Comment: 詳しくありがとうございます。

頂いたサンプルで実装してみると、mが常にnullとなるようで、modelAccessorのTypeを取得できない状況でした。

苦し紛れにCustomHelperの方で、html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Propertiesから必要なデータを取得するようにして回避することはできているのですが、pgrhoさんのアドバイス通り、標準のHelperもきちんと動くようにするのが本来の対処法だと思いますので、何か気づいたことがあれば、ご教示いただければ。

Comment: @HidetoshiKamata 申し訳ありませんが勘違いがありました。`modelAccessor`はプロパティの値を返すので`containerType`は取得できないです。なので拡張メソッドを使う場合の方法に差し替えました。

Comment: 簡単にはMVC2のバグの回避はできなそうな感じですので、標準の`LabelFor`は使わず、自分で拡張した`LabelFor`のみを使う方向で対応で対応することにしました。色々とアドバイスいただき、ありがとうございました。